# User session time control recommendations

Tags: javascript, mysql, postgresql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to solve a problem about time control for users in an app.

Each user only has X minutes to connect to the system. I need to control it every second and log the status into the database.

What database structure would you recommend me?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: My current system is mysql with 3 tables to store session data but I need to check sessions each second but mysql doesn't support it, there're thousands of INSERTS and UPDATES every second :( I'm looking for an "standard" solution or a most efficient solution

Comment: What do you mean does not support it? If you use prepared statements, you will have less overhead, but you will have to have a separate script that only does that action to realize the benefit (so you'd have to use some sort of signaling). More information in your question will give you better answers.

Comment: You mean that they log in and will be logged out after X minutes or they get some kind of one-time login credentials that can be used for up to X minutes?

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Comment: It appears you are asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.